# Sending an email with an attachment to MULTIPLE people

Tags: python, smtplib

I am really new to sending emails in python. I can send individual emails with an attachment, multiple emails without one - but my code wont work for sending multiple emails AND the attachment.

```
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    fromaddr = email_user
    toaddr = ["email"]
    cc = ["email2"]
    bcc = ["email3"]

    subject = "This is the subject"
    body = 'Message for the email' 
    msg = "From: %s\r\n" % fromaddr+ "To: %s\r\n" % toaddr + "CC: %s\r\n" % ",".join(cc) + "Subject: %s\r\n" % subject + "\r\n" + body
    toaddr = toaddr + cc + bcc
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))
    filename ="excelfile.xlsx" 
    attachment=open(filename,'rb')
    part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename= "+filename)
    msg.attach(part)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email_user,email_password)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, message) 
    server.quit()
```

I get the following error... AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'attach'

Comment: You're rewriting the msg variable from MIMEMultipart to Str in the line `msg = "From: %s\r\n" % fromaddr+......`

Comment: Oh I see. How do I add a message and an attachment then?

Comment: I'm unaware of the MIMEMultipart class and it's api, but I just noticed that you were overwriting the variable. You might wanna look into it's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with help of MIMEMultipart and MIMEText (here are the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/email-examples.html)

Basically you just create the attachment with:

```
msg=MIMEMultipart()
part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
part.set_payload(open("attachment.txt", "rb").read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="attachment.txt"')
```

and attach it to the email:

```
msg.attach(part)
```

Heres the full code:

```
import smtplib                                                                          #import libraries for sending Emails(with attachment)
#this is to attach the attachment file
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
#this is for attaching the body of the mail
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)                                            #connects to Email server
server.starttls()
server.user="your@email" 
server.password="yourpassw"
server.login(server.user, server.password)                                              #log in to server

#creates attachment
msg=MIMEMultipart()
part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
part.set_payload(open("attachment.txt", "rb").read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="attachment.txt"')

#attach the attachment
msg.attach(part)

#attach the body
msg.attach(MIMEText("your text"))

#sends mail with attachment
server.sendmail(server.user, ["user@1", "user@2", ...], msg=(msg.as_string()))
server.quit()
```

Comment: Please, add at least an explanation on your answer to prevent you from being downvoted, don't just post pure code

Comment: that makes sense but where do you put the body of the email??